# Complex number as function of real number

Tags: complex-analysis, lambert-w

While seeking all solutions of $ Z ^ 2 = 2 ^ Z $ we have three real roots of $Z : z_1=2, z_2=4, $ and a third real root given in terms of LambertW function:

$ z_3=-\dfrac{2 W\left(\frac{\log (2)}{2}\right)}{\log (2)}\approx -0.7666646960 $

The situation is quite unsymmetrical ( or so it appears to me), so may I ask to

find out the fourth *complex constant root* $z_4$ such that

$$ z_3^{z_{4}} = z_4^{z_{3}} $$

is satisfied.

Reference : A comment by Claude Leibovici to my query regarding above three real roots.

EDIT1:

If $ f(z,a) = z^a - a ^z,$

when $ a=2, $ roots are $ z =(2,4, z_3 ) $

when $ a=4, $ roots are $ z= (2,4, ~ -0.26028 \pm  .869545  i) $

EDIT2:

when $ a=e, $ one root only, it is $ z= e $, don't even know if it is repeated!

And why this *hinging* around $z=e?$

When real constant in the given equation changes real roots do not change but complex parts are changing.

[2^x=x^2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1224539/how-do-i-solve-x2-3-2-3x/1224550?noredirect=1#comment2492083_1224550)

Comment: Do you mean to replace $2$ with $z_3$ in the follow-up question?

Comment: This question stands independently. How to incorporate $2$ into this is entirely in your hands.

Comment: Why do you expect there should be a "symmetry" between the solutions ?

Comment: I was meaning the Edit1 situation

Comment: How do you define w3^w when w is not an integer ?

Comment: earlier situation, Edit 2 , reg $z^e $

Answer (score 0):

The fourth root is actually written in "closed form" just the same as the third root.  Note that $W(x)$ has infinitely many solutions if solutions are allowed to be complex.

This is much like $\ln(x)$ having infinitely many solutions.  When we allow the logarithm to do such, we call it the complex logarithm and it has such properties because of $e^{\theta i}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$ allowing $\theta$ to have the property $\theta=\theta\pm2\pi n,n=0,1,2,3,\cdots$